# How can I return the desired result from this classify(input_string) function?

Tags: python

How can I return this by using the `classify(input_string)` function?

```
classify("I have 35 apples") returns ([35], ['I', 'have', 'apples'])
```

I have tried the following:

```
def classify(input_string):
    input_string=[]
    split=[]
    splits=[]
    for val in input_string:
        try:
            for x in range(len(input_string)):
                spilt=input_string[x:input_string]
                spilts.append(spilt)
                return spilts
        except:
            return None
```

Comment: This `input_string=[]` overwrite your data so you check empty list.

Comment: start with `splits = input_string.split(' ')` and later use `"35".isdigit()` or `int("35")` to recognise numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Split text using `split(' ')` and then use `int()` to recognize numbers

```
def classify(input_string):
    words = []
    numbers = []

    splits = input_string.split(' ')

    for element in splits:
        try:
            val = int(element)
            numbers.append(val)            
        except ValueError:
            words.append(element)

    return (numbers, words)

classify("I have 35 apples")
```

Comment: Thanks you very much sir. Passed all the test cases! Just one modification is needed which is: 
splits=input_strings.split()